# Does the Date object ever use a non-Gregorian calendar?

Tags: javascript, date, calendar

Does the `Date` object in Javascript ever use a non-Gregorian calendar?

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC) docs outline the methods on the `Date` object and reference [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC) and [IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14).

The Wikipedia article mentions

> Days are conventionally identified using the Gregorian calendar, but Julian day numbers can also be used.

The MDN and MSDN documentation just says that the non-UTC methods refer to the "local time", but doesn't define what "local time" is.

I am working on interfacing to a webservice which is giving me back some data that includes a day-of-year field, which I need to compare to current day-of-year.  I am well aware about the pitfalls of relying on an accurate time from a user's machine, and am fine with any problems that result from bad timezones and bogus date settings.

I am concerned, though, about users in locales that don't use the Gregorian calendar, and what their browsers will give back if I use the `.getDate()`, `.getMonth()`, and `.getFullYear()` methods to compute day-of-year.

So, in practice, does "local time" in Javascript ever refer to a non-Gregorian calendar system, such as the Hebrew or Persian calendars?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "local time" refers to the time zone offset from UTC.  However the question is still interesting: can `getMonth()` ever return something bigger than 11, for instance.  I strongly suspect the answer is "no" but I've got no evidence.

Comment: @Pointy, the ECMA-262 specs do say that local time == utc + time zone adjustment + daylight dayings time adjustment.  However, we all know what the specs say and what browsers do aren't always the same thing.

Comment: Julian days aren't a separate calendar system -- a Julian Day is simply the fractional number of days since noon on January 1, 4713 BC.  Kind of like UNIX time, except with days, and with a much longer-ago epoch. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

Comment: @duskwuff yes but computer people since like forever (believe me, I'm pretty old) have been mis-using the terminology - "Julian Date" usually means "day-of-year"

Comment: I edited the question.  When I was writing it, I did get "Julian day" and "Julian calendar" mixed up in my head.  Someone using the Hebrew, Persian, etc, calendars is what I am really contemplating.

Comment: When I hear "Gregorian calandar", I always think that jon skeet will be there in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ECMAScript](http://www.ecmascript.org/) specs ([3rd edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) and [5th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262%205th%20edition%20December%202009.pdf) are nearly identical in this regard, but am quoting the 5th):

> **15.9.1.9 Local Time**
>
> Conversion from UTC to local time is defined by 
>   `LocalTime(t) = t + LocalTZA + DaylightSavingTA(t)` 
>   Conversion from local time to UTC is defined by 
>   `UTC(t) = t – LocalTZA – DaylightSavingTA(t – LocalTZA)` 
>   Note that `UTC(LocalTime(t))` is not necessarily always equal to `t`.

`LocalTZA` refers to local time zone adjustment, and `DaylightSavingTA` is the adjustment for daylight savings.

I have not found any evidence of a browser (current or historic) that does anything different when a non-Gregorian calendar is enabled on a user's machine.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested by setting my computer (Mac OS X 10.7.4) to use the Hebrew calendar, and the behavior of the Date object was not affected in Safari, Firefox, or Chrome. Looks like it always uses the Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 2):

Re: Does the Date object in Javascript ever use a non-Gregorian calendar?

No. I don't see any backup for a claim that the Javascript Date object can use the Julian Calendar system.

However, you can convert a Javascript date object (a Gregorian date) into either a [Julian Day](http://javascript.about.com/library/bljulday.htm) or a [Julian Date](http://javascript.about.com/library/bljuldate.htm).

**Julian Day**

> > Julian day is used in the Julian date (JD) system of time measurement for scientific use by the astronomy community, presenting the interval of time in days and fractions of a day since January 1, 4713 BC Greenwich noon. Julian date is recommended for astronomical use by the International Astronomical Union.

**Julian Date**

> > The term Julian date is widely used to refer to the day-of-year (ordinal date) although this usage is not strictly in accord to standards set by some international organizations.

*Source for the above quotes is a wikipedia article, [Julian_day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)

Note that neither format involves months since "Julian date" and "Julian day" are terms for a particular representation of a day in the Gregorian calendar. You can tell this by the fact that the Julian day definition uses a Gregorian date: "4713 BC Greenwich noon"