# C++ and Windows: Is SYSTEMTIME always based on the Gregorian calendar?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, time

I have a SYSTEMTIME struct. This struct may either contain a UTC time or a local time that was returned from a Windows API function at some prior point and time.

In C++ I am calculating the day of the year based on the SYSTEMTIME that a function returns. In other words how many days since Jan 1. In order to do that I need to be mindful of the extra day during leap years, Feburary 29. That's all easy enough if I knew that the SYSTEMTIME is always based on the gregorian calendar.

If a user in a foreign country uses some other calendar system wouldn't I have a problem calculating the day of the year? I can't seem to do this on my machine to test the theory, and I don't even know if it's plausible. Any Microsoft experts that can help me out here?

Maybe a better question would be is there already a Windows API function that calculates the day of the year based on a SYSTEMTIME? I can't find one.

The closest thing I could find searching is [this javascript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723638/does-the-date-object-ever-use-a-non-gregorian-calendar), which is interesting but I think very different from what I'm asking. I won't see any replies to this question until tomorrow (Monday) so if there are any follow up questions I will answer them then.

Thanks!

edit: I found this article but it still doesn't answer the question:
[OS level support for non-Gregorian calendars? - Sorting it all Out - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](http://www.siao2.com/2010/03/31/9986458.aspx)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Windows API always returns and interprets SYSTEMTIME based on the Gregorian calendar.  I've asked MS (via the MSDN feedback tool) to add this to the documentation, though I expect it will take some time for them to consider the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at [SYSTEMTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tc6fd5zs.aspx) on MSDN, it says:

> Retrieves the current system date and time.  The system time is expressed in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

It seems that regardless, SYSTEMTIME works in the Gregorian calendar.

Best of luck, I hope that I was of help.